# como puedo acceder a las vistas si no tiene un controlodar codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

estoy aprendiendo de codeigniter

quiero acceder al menu para editarlo se encuentra en `view/layout/menu.php`
pero cuando quiero acceder desde la url no me deja por que no tiene un controlador.

**An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter maneja el "MVC" por lo cual, por seguridad, no podrias acceder a dicho elemento, sin mandarlo a llamar en el controlador. 
Las vistas no son accesibles desde la url. Tienes que setearlo en tu controlador.

Asi, cuando entraras a www.local.com/index.php/nombre_del_controlador/
deberas de ver tu menu.

por ejemplo:

```
public function index(){
 $this->load->view('layout/menu'); //Codeigniter, ya sabe que tiene que buscar en views
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que veo desde el principio es que desea cargar una vista y no llamar a un controlador. El mensaje de error se debe a que CodeIgniters Router busca un controlador de "view". Dentro de ese controlador está intentando llamar la función de "layout". Esto se debe a que el esquema de enrutamiento predeterminado de codeigniter se interpreta de la siguiente manera:

```
base_url / controller / function.
```

[Le recomiendo que visite esta documentación para comprender mejor el sistema de enrutamiento.](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Ahora no entiendo realmente por qué está intentando acceder al archivo menu.php a través de la barra de direcciones. Si está intentando editar un archivo php que contiene html, deberá navegar por la estructura de su directorio. El siguiente es un ejemplo de dónde podría encontrar el archivo que está buscando.

```
Aplicación / views / layout / menu.php
```

Aparte de esto, sería útil si compartes parte del código con el que está trabajando y trata de elaborar más sobre su pregunta.